# When are Events Disjoint?

Tags: probability

We throw a fair coin twice. Let $K_i, \quad i=1,2$ be the event that head occurs at the $i-th$ throw. Then apparently $K_1$ and $K_2$ are not disjoint.

I'm not sure if I can see that. For a normal coin throwing experiment, we have

$\Omega=\{\text{H,T}\}$

$\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset, \{H\}, \{T\}, \{H,T\}\}$

$P[X] = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} \quad, X=\text{H} \\ \frac{1}{2} \quad, X=\text{T} \end{cases}$

right? I hope I got that right. Now to be able to talk about the "i-th" occurence of head, I need to define a sequence of random variables, right?

So our experiment would consist of

$X_i \sim Be(\frac{1}{2}), \quad i=1,2 \tag{1}$

So to answer the question: Are $K_1, K_2$ disjoint? I need to somehow be able to relate them. But I fail to do that. I couldn't write down a proof for it and I think I kind of lack the intuition.

Comment: What if you toss heads twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one throw of a coin then as outcome space we can take $\Omega=\{H,T\}$ and as $\sigma$-algebra: $\mathcal P(\Omega)=\{\varnothing,\{H\},\{T\},\{H,T\}\}$

If there are two throws then as outcome space we can take $\Omega'=\Omega\times\Omega$ and as $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal P(\Omega')$.

If $K_1$ denotes the event that the first throw gives heads then: $$K_1=\{(H,H),(H,T)\}$$

If $K_2$ denotes the event that the second throw gives heads then: $$K_2=\{(H,H),(T,H)\}$$

Observe that: $$K_1\cap K_2=\{(H,H)\}\neq\varnothing$$
Showing that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are not disjoint.

---

In short: two events in the same probability space are disjoint iff it is not possible that both occur.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That just made so many things so much clearer.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The main error is because if you toss the coin twice (without restrictions) the sample space is

$$\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega_4\}=\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$$

with probabilities

$$\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\}$$

and not simply $\Omega=\{H,T\}$